# Implicit function theorem, a particular case.

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

I have a question regarding the correct use of the implicit function theorem. Suppose I have the following equation:

\begin{equation}
P = f (\xi,Y)
\end{equation}

I'm interested in the effect of $\xi$ on the $Y$ variable. For this, I would like to define:

\begin{equation}
F(\xi,Y) = P - f (\xi,Y) = 0
\end{equation}

I think I can't use the implicit function theorem according to the following formula:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial \xi } = - \frac{ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \xi }  }{  \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y }  }
\end{equation}

Because $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y }  = \frac{\partial P}{\partial Y }   - \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y } = 0 $, since $P = f(\xi , Y)$.

Is this right? Or should I treat the variable $P$ as a constant?